# Is it possible to turn off the auto-pathing for the Pathauto module?

Tags: path-aliases

I want to avoid the Pathauto module automatically creates node path aliases.

Is there a way to disable it?
I could want to enable it later, so I don't want the module cannot anymore automatically create path aliases.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is possible without implement the `hook_form_alter()` function but you can use a different approach to solve the issue.

You can use a custom field instead that the title of the node.
Set the field as "Required" and in `/admin/config/search/path/patterns`set the pattern of the node with the token of the field instead that the title (ie: [node:field-seotitle] ).

In other words:

- Add a field in your content type, for example: seotitle;
- Set the field as Required;
- Go in `/admin/config/search/path/patterns`;
- Set the pattern of the your content type where you have add the field with the token of the seotitle field (ie: your-content-type/[node:field_seotitle]);

In this way you can choose a title for the path alias and save the node only until you have a seo-title;

I hope I explained myself.